# Casperjs - trying to run casper script from command line doesn't output correctly

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, phantomjs, casperjs

I'm brand new to casperjs, and in the process of trying to run my first casper script from the command line (using `$ casperjs sample.js`), I received this output:

```
Casper CLI passed args:
[]
Casper CLI passed options:
{
    "casper-path": "/usr/local/Cellar/casperjs/1.1-beta2/libexec",
    "cli": true
}
```

Instead of the predicted output of:

```
CasperJS, a navigation scripting and testing utility for PhantomJS
PhantomJS: Headless WebKit with JavaScript API
```

Here are the contents of the sample file:

```
var casper = require('casper').create();

casper.start('http://casperjs.org/', function() {
    this.echo(this.getTitle());
});

casper.thenOpen('http://phantomjs.org', function() {
    this.echo(this.getTitle());
});

casper.run();
```

I installed casperjs using the latest version of homebrew.

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you aren't running the sample that you think you are.

The output you gave came from this code:

```
var casper = require("casper").create();

casper.echo("Casper CLI passed args:");
require("utils").dump(casper.cli.args);

casper.echo("Casper CLI passed options:");
require("utils").dump(casper.cli.options);

casper.exit();
```

You could try running `less sample.js` to verify the contents of `sample.js`.

[Source](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/cli.html#using-the-command-line)

Comment: Apparently I had accidentally made a duplicate by the same name with different contents. This helped me catch it. Thanks!